# Stored procedure for inserting default value based on column type

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out how to create a stored procedure which takes a table as input and then inserts values in all of the columns based on the column type.

For example: the table `Dim.Name` has two columns; the first is `ID` which is an `int` and the second is `Name` which is of type `nvarchar`:

| ID(int) | Name(nvarchar) |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

I'm trying to figure out how to create a stored procedure that will take the table as a input and insert '-1' for all the `int` columns and 'Unknown' for all the `nvarchar` columns.

So the desired result would be

```
dbo.usp_InsertData(Dim.Name)
```

| ID(int) | Name(nvarchar) |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | Unknown |

Comment: Don't, honestly. This type of "Do X for *anything*" procedure isn't something suited to the SQL Language. Don't try to treat SQL like a programming language or scripting language, it is *not*. If you want a procedure to handle inserts to a table, design it for a **specific** table (or related tables in some cases). If you have another table, create a *second* procedure for that table. etc, etc.

Comment: attempt to invent the silver bullet ?

Comment: While the goal is questionable, you will need to refer to [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and write dynamic sql to accomplish your goal. Some simple searching will find code that does part of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dynamic `INSERT` using `sys.columns`

Exactly *why* you would want to do this is another question.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE WeirdInsert
  @schema sysname,
  @table  sysname
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT '
INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table) + '
(' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ', ') + ')
VALUES (' + STRING_AGG(
      CASE WHEN c.system_type_id IN (34,35,99,167,167,175,231,239)
           THEN '''Unknown'''
           WHEN c.system_type_id IN (48,52,56,59,60,62,106,108,122,127)
           THEN '-1'
           ELSE 'DEFAULT'
      END , ', ')
      + ');'
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name = @table
      AND s.name = @schema
);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;  -- can also pass parameters
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e9fea/1)